# Pun 2 having issues with making a lobby

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I am developing a multiplayer game using Unity and Pun 2.
I am trying to make a room/lobby.

It works as expected each time I run it but I get an error message in the console.

[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEDlE.png)

*"JoinOrCreateRoom failed. Client is on MasterServer (must be Master Server for matchmaking)but not ready for operations (State: Joining). Wait for callback: OnJoinedLobby or OnConnectedToMaster.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)"*

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class RoomManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public GameObject player;
    [Space]
    public Transform spawnPoint;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connecting...");

        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }

    
    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        base.OnConnectedToMaster();

        Debug.Log("Connected to Server");

        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();

    }



    public override void OnJoinedLobby()
    {
        base.OnJoinedLobby();

        PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom("test", null, null);

        Debug.Log("We're in the lobby");

        PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom("test", null, null);

    }


    public override void OnJoinedRoom()

    { 
        base.OnJoinedRoom();


        Debug.Log("We're connected and in a room!");

        GameObject _player_ = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(player.name, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

I changed the order of the code before the *we're in the lobby* state hoping that it would get rid of the error message. It stayed the same.

This is my first coding project, I am following a tutorial that had other bugs but I solved them by looking for answers/playing with the code.